# Issues with results from joomla database to screen

Tags: database, joomla

I seem to be stuck. I have checked this document [JDatabase 3.0](http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase/3.0)

And i cant figure out why my rusults from the column wont display on the screen.
Its possible its an issue with the WHERE statement but it does echo out the correct username so I'm not sure. Here is the code I have been manipulating.

```
{source 0}
<?php
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
if (!$user->guest)
$name = $user->username;

$db =& JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query = "SELECT image_url FROM #__image_data WHERE user_name = $name";

$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->image_url();  //also tried $results = $db->loadObjectList
                                       and loadAssocList

echo $results

?>
{/source}
```

Comment: I really would recommend using 
$query->select($db->qn('image_url');
$query->from($db->qn('#__image_data');
$query->where($db->qn('user_name') . ' = ' . $db->q($name));

It's more characters but you know the quoting will be right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
$list = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach ($list as $item){
    echo $item->image_url.'<br />';
}
```

Comment: If I change the last part $result and replace with your code I then get a error page "Error: 0 - SQL=SELECT image_url FROM foxy_image_data WHERE user_name = Flexxall"

Comment: Got it i needed to put '$name' in query line

Comment: Use dbQuote for strings and dbQuotename for fields and tables.

Comment: I dont understand the dbquote and quotename could you give an example ? I looked the document and it looks like the proper form i should use but i am unclear on the exact usage in my qbove query

Comment: @Elin I tried doing this but it gives me a blank page 'code'$query->select($db->qn('image_url'); $query->from($db->qn('#__image_data'); $query->where($db->qn('user_name') . ' = ' . $db->q($name));

Comment: Do you have error reporting and debug on? Check the generated query and find the mistake. Can you paste the generated query here?

What you are doing is making sure that you are using `` around the names of tables and fields and '' around strings.  The check the = is  doing is to compare to  a value of a string not to where two  fields are the same value.